# How to access the return variable of a function in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to access data from an HTML form and use it in Flask. I was successfully able to get the data but I am not quite sure how to return it through function and use the returned variable inside FLask as a global variable.

```
@app.route('/form',methods=["POST"])
def search():
    company=request.form.get("symbol"
    return render_template('chart.html', Name=company)
```

I am only able to use the data of the `company` variable inside the function but I want to be able to use it outside the function. I have tried calling the function but it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return with render_template(), then the `company` variable will be available only inside the function and the html file.

For accessing outside function

1. Try making a class and then set the `self.company` in the method
2. Return `company` from the function and have a separate
   rendering logic.